# Does variance depend linearly on beta?

Tags: variance, finance

Under the CAPM, consider an investment with stochastic cash flows.
Does the variance of the return on the investment depend linearly on beta? if not, why so?

Comment: @Dave, the `beta-distribution` tag is irrelevant here, as none of the variables follow it.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple CAPM model you usually assume that $r_{i} = \beta_i  r_m + \epsilon_{i}$ with $\epsilon_{i} \sim N(0, \sigma_i)$, where $r_{i}$ is the return of asset $i$, $r_m$ is the market return, and $\sigma_i$ is the idiosyncratic volatility of asset $i$. (Edit: note that the returns used should be net of the risk-free rate as Richard pointed out in the comments).

Since we also assume that idiosyncratic risk is independent of market risk (i.e. $\text{E}[r_m\epsilon_{i}] = 0$), we get that $\text{Var}(r_{i}) = \text{Var}(\beta_ir_m) + \text{Var}(\epsilon_{i}) = \beta_i^2\sigma_m^2 + \sigma_i^2$, where $\sigma_m$ is market volatility. So you get that variance depends linearly on the square of beta. This is because $\text{Var}(aX) = a^2\text{Var}(x)$ if $a$ is assumed to be known (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Propagation)

Comment: You forgot the risk free rate. If you interpret $r_i$ and $r_m$ as returns net of the risk-free rate, then the first equation is fine (though normality of errors is unnecessary). Also, what is $m_t$?

Comment: @RichardHardy You're absolutely right. I adjusted the answer accordingly.